# vb.net how to convert picturebox to bitmap

Tags: vb.net

I want pixel color value of the picturebox 
I assigned text to the picturebox & now want to get the value of color of each pixel
What is method of picturebox or i should convert it to bitmap? How?
in vb6 there is getpixel() method to get color value
What is in .net?

Answer (score 4):

If you can convert it into a bitmap, it's a breeze:

```
Dim MyBitmap As New Bitmap(MyPicturebox.Image)
Dim MyColor As Color
MyColor = MyBitmap.GetPixel(X of your pixel, Y of your pixel)
```

You might want to loop through the pixels, which is not hard if you know the width and height.

Comment: But i does not assigned image to picturebox i assigned text using drawstring                                                          Dim g As Graphics = Picture1.CreateGraphics              g.DrawString(TxtMsg.Text, f, New SolidBrush(Color.Red), 0, 0)